# Is it relevant to partition by Business Date and Ingest Date for a FACT table on Delta Lake?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, hadoop-partitioning

I am working on a data engineering case where i have a table `Table_Movie` partitionned by **`ingest date`**. Now, from time to time, i receive some old data. And I need to perform operations based on **`business date`**.

*For example :*
Today, I received new data corresponding to the date 12/05/2020:

1. I need to delete in `Table_Movie` the data corresponding to the `business date` **12/05/2020**
2. Once the old data deleted, i need to insert the new data corresponding to **12/05/2020**.

Would it improve performance to partition by `ingest date` **and** `business date` ? :

==>  `eg. Table_Movie/ingestdate=20220812/business_date=20200512/`

Note : we need to keep the partitionning with `ingest date` for other reasons.

Please let me know if you have any suggestion or guidance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only occasionally receive the old data, then with partitioning by business date you may get very small files, and this will affect performance. Delta on Databricks uses multiple optimization techniques to avoid reading not necessary data.  One of this techniques is [Data Skipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/delta/optimizations/file-mgmt#--data-skipping) - when writing data Delta will record the min & max values for indexed columns, so when reading with condition on indexed column, driver will check value against this index, and skip files that doesn't have the data.  Data Skipping is enabled by default for first N columns (32 by default, and configurable), so you need to make sure that business date column is at the beginning of the columns list.

Comment: thanks Alex ! I understand that i don't have to index the 'business date' column, if it is in the first 32 fields.  Also that partitionning by 'business date' would not be good in this case.  Do you know when this index needs to be refreshed ?

Comment: the statistics is collected automatically when you write data, so you don't need to do anything.